# Want to pull list of emps turning 50 in a given year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have been able to pull there age but when I do a where for "50" I get error. when I rem out last part I get everyone and their age. I only want emp that will be 50 this year. and to be able to use it each yr from here out.  this is for sql server 2008

```
SELECT FLOOR((CAST (GetDate() AS INTEGER) - CAST([Employee_Date_List4] AS INTEGER)) / 365.25) AS Age 
,[Employee_Name]
,[Employee_Date_List4]
from [Forefront].[dbo].[PR_EMPLOYEE_MASTER_1_MC] 
where Company_Code = 'tmg' 
--and (select FLOOR((CAST (GetDate() AS INTEGER) - CAST([Employee_Date_List4] AS INTEGER)) / 365.25) 
--from [Forefront].[dbo].[PR_EMPLOYEE_MASTER_1_MC])  = '50'
```

Comment: you could simply use `datediff(yy, GETDATE(), Employee_Date_List4)`

Comment: You'd need to check the IDs of the records in the main query and the subquery are the same. Better, use a CTE.

Comment: Here is a good write up on calculating age.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/samlester/archive/2012/11/30/tsql-solve-it-your-way-finding-an-employee-s-current-age-based-on-birth-date.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression:

```
FLOOR((CAST (GetDate() AS INTEGER) - CAST([Employee_Date_List4] AS INTEGER)) / 365.25) AS Age
```

Is not a good expression for `Age`.  You generally want to see if the current day of the year is on or after the day of year of the person's birthdate.

That said, to tell who turns 50 *this year* is easy:

```
SELECT 
    [Employee_Name]
    [Employee_Date_List4]
from [Forefront].[dbo].[PR_EMPLOYEE_MASTER_1_MC] 
where Company_Code = 'tmg' 
AND YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR([Employee_Date_List4]) = 50  // just need to compare the years
```

Answer (score 2):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/65bb8/4/0):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(year, Employee_Date_List4, GETDATE()) AS Age,
   Employee_Name, Employee_Date_List4
FROM PR_EMPLOYEE_MASTER_1_MC
WHERE Company_Code = 'tmg' 
AND DATEDIFF(year, Employee_Date_List4, GETDATE()) = 50;
```

For more information check out [**DATEDIFF ()**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

Comment: `DATEDIFF` is not a good method of calculating Age. `DATEDIFF(year, 12-31-2013,1-1-2014)` will give you 1 even though they're only 1 day apart.